# Python (Pandas) - Drop rows with NAs and convert values to boolean

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Trying to drop rows with missing data which is "?" is this case and convert last column(income) into boolean. Followed couple answers on StackOverflow but still won't work. Here is the code:

```
%pylab inline
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

fileURL = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data'

df = pd.read_csv(fileURL, 
                 names=['age','type_employer', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 
                        'education_num', 'marital', 'occupation', 'relationship', 
                        'race','sex','capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hr_per_week','country', 'income'],  
                 na_values = ['?'])

df = df.dropna(how='any')
boolean = {'>50K': True, '<=50K': False}
df['income'].map(boolean)
df
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: rows with '?' are still there , values '<=50K' and '>50K' are still there instead of true/false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had almost the right method, but you are catching extra spaces in parsing. CSV is not supposed to have spaces.

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileURL, 
             names=['age','type_employer', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 
                    'education_num', 'marital', 'occupation', 
                    'relationship', 
                    'race','sex','capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 
                    'hr_per_week','country', 'income'],  
             na_values = [' ?'])

df = df.dropna(how='any')
boolean = {' >50K': True, ' <=50K': False}
df['income'] = df['income'].map(boolean)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1. df['income'] = df['income'].applymap(boolean)
2. df.dropna(how='any', axis=1, inplace = True)
```

note `applymap` and `axis`

Comment: 1. Rows that contain  "?" are still there 2. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: what is the name of these columns (that contain "?")

Comment: as example row 14 has '?' under 'country'

Comment: try again brother

Comment: `df['income']` is a series... you can get away with `df['income'].apply(boolean)`